# Microsoft Graph API MFA Status Reporting

Tags: api, graph, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to create a report for our clients that will list what users have MFA enabled, enforced, or disabled. We used to use a powershell script to report this that didn't involve the GRAPH API but we're moving all of our reporting over to Graph. [I see there is an endpoint in Graph for this information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
But it returns 2 true or false values about the user's registration. When I compare the list I get back from the API call to the list of user's MFA status from the office admin portal, I can't find a correlation between these True False values and the actual MFA status. Some users will have both false values but will have MFA enabled. Some users will have true and false values but have MFA disabled. Has anyone else used this endpoint and know how to get usable data out of it? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the information this endpoint is giving and it's not for Microsoft 365 MFA?